# vb.net: Why does my datagridview insist on combining 2 different sql searches?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

This code block works OK if both cases are not met. Unfortunately, if both cases are met in the same instance run of a program, the two columns for the searches are combined, or incremented. But the results do not combine. Just the columns. For example: Case "Server" would have columns A1, A2, A3 No matter how many times i run thru case server, it would be just fine. But if I run case "Patients", my columns would now be A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3. It's the same if i run case patients then case server, but the columns would be in a different order.

```
Private Sub frmSearch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With dgvSearch
        dt.Clear()
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .Columns.Clear()
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill 'this does not allow resizing of column width
        Select Case formSwitch
            Case "Server"
                sql = "Select cnn, server, port, uid, detail from tbl_cnnstrings"
                SelectQuery(lcnn, 3)
                .DataSource = dt
                .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Connection Name"
                .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Server"
                .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Port"
                .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Uid"
                .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Detail"

                Try     'this code block resizes column and bypass error
                    .Columns(2).Width = 50
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Case "Patients"
                sql = "Select concat(patientid_yr, '-', patientid_m, '-', patientid_no) as patientid, concat_ws(' ', lname, ',', fname, ' ', mname) as name from tbl_patinfo order by name;"
                SelectQuery(cnn, 3)
                .DataSource = dt
                .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Patient ID"
                .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Patient Name"
                Try     'this code block resizes column and bypass error
                    .Columns(0).Width = 100
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
        End Select

    End With
End Sub
```

My theory is that I'm not properly clearing the data table.
FYI: dt = data table, da = mysqldataadapter, SelectQuery = a custom sub for the mysql connections and queries. lcnn, and cnn are just connection strings.
Sample output:
http://i58.tinypic.com/30jkwb9.png

Comment: If you're going to downvote me you could at least explain. I'm pretty sure i took a bath today.

Answer (score 1):

The grid is not going to remove any columns automatically.  It will add new columns automatically but you have to remove them manually.  If you're going to change the data source then set `DataSource` to Nothing first, then `Clear` the `Columns` collection, then set the `DataSource` again.

Comment: I added .DataSource = Nothing and .Columns.Clear() below dt.clear(). Nothing's changed. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Show us your current code.  Just add it as an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Put dt.clear() in each case instead of outside the case statements, or I would just have different datatable and command for each query, give it a try, I am sorry if I wasn't any help...

Comment: I'm going to try this. But logically speaking it shouldn't be that different. Since it's not going to skip the line anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = New Datatable
```

I found my mistake. Apparently I have to declare my datatable as new everytime I use it. Otherwise the data inside will keep appending.